# AngularJS Get all values from an array in Javascript and push it to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var items = [
  {name: 'Tyres'},
  {name: 'Computers'},
  {name: 'Leather'},
  {name: 'Furniture'},
  {name: 'Electronics'}
];
```

**I want to print this array or console.log it in javascript like this.**

```
Tyres,Computers,Leather,Furniture,Electronics
```

**I dont want the key from this array. I just want to print values from this array. kindly help me with this. Thanks**

Comment: Just ignore the title of this question. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You need to attempt to solve the question yourself...  Asking for questions to be solved for you does not really help you learn and grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like the following. Firstly, get all the names by using `map` and then use `join(',')` to turn it from an array into a string and separate each item with a comma.

```js
const items = [
  {name: 'Tyres'},
  {name: 'Computers'},
  {name: 'Leather'},
  {name: 'Furniture'},
  {name: 'Electronics'}
];

console.log(items.map(i => i.name).join(','));
```

Comment: Thanks Paul Fitzgerald it really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to [map](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d) the items, returning only the desired parameter value:

in es6:

```
console.log(items.map(i => i.name));
```

in older js:

```
console.log(items.map(function(i) { return i.name; }));
```

edit (for op's comment):

to get just a string of the values, try using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).  you can chain it right onto the end of the map function like so:

```
console.log(items.map(i => i.name).join(','));
```

this will join the array values into a single string, using the delimiter specified to separate the values.

Comment: Thanks @derelict it really helped but I it still gives me values like `["Tyres","Leather"]` I just want it like `Tyres,Leather`. Kindly help me out with it. Thanks